# DOM listeners lost if a component is wrapped within multiple HOC

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

I am using a [react-click-outside] library to detect clicking outside of an element.

The problem is that if I have another high order component, the library only works if it is the closest wrapper component. e.g:

In this case clicking outside works:

```
export default injectIntl(enhanceWithClickOutside(Menu));
```

But in this case it does not:

```
export default enhanceWithClickOutside(injectIntl(Menu));
```

Comment: Could you expand on why this is a problem for you?

Comment: This is becoming a bigger problem if we have multiple HOC-s that trying to manipulate the DOM. Then only one of them works not the other one.